# Visual c++ /clr errors

Tags: visual-c++

So I had this error with my Visual C++ program that uses a button to connect to a camera, record a video, and save the video then disconnect from the camera. In order to solve this issue, I type /clr in the command line of the c/c++ properties. The errors were

```
1>c:\users\taycm_000\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test-new\test\stdafx.h(28): error C3641: 'handleObjectEvent' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>c:\users\taycm_000\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test-new\test\stdafx.h(32): error C3641: 'handlePropertyEvent' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>c:\users\taycm_000\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test-new\test\stdafx.h(37): error C3641: 'handleStateEvent' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
```

Is there a way to solve these errors without using /clr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++/CLI compiler isn't very thrilled when you say "compile all code to IL" and it encounters a declaration of a function that is clearly a function that was compiled to native code.  It cannot be both.

Be sure to tell it which headers contain declarations for native code functions.  You can switch back-and-forth on the fly.  Easy to do with a pragma:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "foo.h"
#pragma managed(pop)
```